# Is is possible to check if an email exists in the database using Laravel 5.7 Validation features (for Password Resets)

Tags: laravel-5.7

I want to send an email with a link, so that the user can reset his password. I need to check first if the email exists in the system. Does Laravel 5.7 validation features has the ability to check this or will I have to use Eloquent and search for the email?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes you can use laravel validation rules. something like:

```
'email' => 'required|email|exists:users,email'
```

[more description](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-exists)

Comment: how about check if email exists